# Does running Puppeteer on Google Cloud Functions download Chromium browser on the fly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

When running a Google Cloud or Firebase Function running puppeteer, does it download the full Chromium from a public download url during the function execution? How long does that take? Is that considered ingress and free? Are there any optimizations for this? e.g., Is it worthwhile to cache a private download of Chromium to Cloud Storage? Any other tips or gotchas?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems Chromium is downloaded on npm install, so I'm still wondering how that works with respect to function execution and cold start latency? Does GCF have optimizations specific to headless Chrome?